# match only the last instance of a pattern with Javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove size data from a file name like

```
var src = 'http://az648995.vo.msecnd.net/win/2015/11/Halo-1024x551.jpg';
src = src.replace(
     /-\d+x\d+(.\S+)$/,
    function( match, contents, offset, s ) {
        return contents;
    }
);
```

this works as expected and i get

```
http://az648995.vo.msecnd.net/win/2015/11/Halo.jpg
```

But if I have a filename like

```
http://az648995.vo.msecnd.net/win/2015/11/slot-Drake-08-2000x1000-1024x512.jpg
```

it returns

```
http://az648995.vo.msecnd.net/win/2015/11/slot-Drake-08-1024x512.jpg
```

instead of the desired

```
http://az648995.vo.msecnd.net/win/2015/11/slot-Drake-08-2000x1000.jpg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex does not work as expected primarily because of an unescaped dot in  `(.\S+)$` part. An unescaped `.` matches any character but a newline. However, `\S` matches any non-whitespace, including a `.`. Besides unnecessary backtracking, you may get an unexpected result with a string like [`http://az648995.vo.msecnd.net/win/2015/11/slot-Drake-08-2000x1000-1024x512.MORE_TEXT_HERE.jpg`](https://regex101.com/r/eG9zD6/2).

Assuming the extension is the part of a string after the last dot, you can use

```
-\d+x\d+(\.[^.\s]+)$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eG9zD6/1)

The nagated character class `[^.\s]` matches any character but whitespace and a literal `.` symbol. Note that there is no point in using a callback function inside a replace, you can use a mere `$1` backreference.

JS demo:

```js
var src = 'http://az648995.vo.msecnd.net/win/2015/11/slot-Drake-08-2000x1000-1024x512.jpg';
src = src.replace(/-\d+x\d+(.[^.\s]+)$/, "$1");
document.body.innerHTML = src;
```

Comment: A capturing group is a piece of a pattern enclosed in a pair of unescaped parentheses. A `$n` is called a replacement backreference. I use terminology from regular-expressions.info, I think it describes NFA regex engines best.

Answer (score 3):

Try escaping the `.` and you will be fine:

```
/-\d+x\d+(\.\S+)$/
```

Comment: Just FYI: `/-\d+x\d+(\.\S+)$/` may return unexpected results since `\S` also matches `.`.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly change the regex to be a little more explicit:

```
/-\d+x\d+(\.[^\s-]+)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex can be simplified to the following

Replace

```
-\d+x\d+(\.\S+)
```

With

```
$1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my recent project, more than once i had encountered the need of matching only the last match where there can be multiple matches of the same pattern in a string. So kind of `lastIndexOfMatch`.

In your case if the matching pattern is `/-\d+x\d+/` then you can simply convert it to match the last matching pattern by `/-\d+x\d+(?!.*-\d+x\d+)/`. Which means a matching pattern where the remaining part of the string can not contain the same matching pattern. Lets see it in action.

```js
let uri = "http://az648995.vo.msecnd.net/win/2015/11/slot-Drake-08-2000x1000-1024x512.jpg",
    idx = uri.search(/-\d+x\d+(?!.*-\d+x\d+)/),      // lastIndexOfMatch
    res = uri.replace(/-\d+x\d+(?!.*-\d+x\d+)/, ""); // replace the last appearance with ""
console.log(idx);
console.log(res);
```